# Are dead mice by my compost heap a sign of trouble?

Tags: pests, compost

I have a compost heap at the back of my property, probably 30-40 feet away from the house. It's one of those simple "circle of chicken wire on bare earth" ones, with most of the material being [rotting vegetables from the boxes my wife gets](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/is-it-ok-to-put-moldy-fruits-and-vegetables-in-the-compost-heap) and maybe an occasional leftover bone that's been stripped of meat. I don't really compost seriously, mainly using it so I don't feel so guilty when a fruit or vegetable goes unused and we toss it in there. About a month ago, I noticed that things seemed to be "escaping" out of a hole, which I initially assumed was just a matter of the soil within collapsing and there being a depression on the ground, but it's been happening fairly often even when I fill things in. More recently, I found two halves of a dead mouse by the compost heap, and today, I found a whole dead mouse. I haven't seen any live ones yet, but:

1. it worries me a bit that I might be attracting vermin and
2. I'm not certain why they're turning up dead next to the heap.

Comment: The mice are enjoying the compost, and something (a cat?) is hunting them.

Comment: Probably the case. I'm hoping nothing in the compost is leading to all of the deaths.

Comment: Your compost method is undoubtedly attracting vermin. Whatever it is that's killing the mice, it's not your compost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you live near anyone else? I live in the suburbs and folks in our area regularly debate the issue of using poison to get rid of mice and rats. When a mouse is poisoned it will die somewhere else later. If you find a whole mouse it's possible (likely?) that it was poisoned somewhere and came and died where you were.

To reduce the vermin you can:

- tweak the things you compost so you are not composting items that attract them (the bones and whole food - chop it up smaller first, ideally, to accelerate the decomposition process).
- turn the pile and keep the moisture levels and mix of carbon/nitrogen right so that it is hot. When the pile is hot it is less attractive to vermin.
- Use a different compost style (e.g. a turning bin) that is harder for the vermin to get into. You can keep using your chicken-wire for longer term aging out the partially composted materials once they are composted enough that mice would be less interested in them.